# Check that module implements behaviour

Tags: elixir

I have a behaviour and a function that takes a list of modules that should implement that behaviour. I would like to check that each module passed in does in fact implement that behaviour. I can do that with `MyBehaviour.implemented_by?/1` below, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way about it.

```
defmodule MyBehaviour do
  @callback do_something(String.t(), String.t()) :: no_return()

  def implemented_by?(module) do
    :attributes
    |> module.module_info()
    |> Enum.member?({:behaviour, [__MODULE__]})
  end
end
```

**Is that the best way to check that?** I'm not finding anything in the docs or Elixir forum or anywhere.

**Should I even be checking that?** Or should I just let the responsibility rest entirely upon the caller? Are behaviours more about "I want to make sure I implement everything needed" than "I want everyone else to know I implement everything needed"?

**Is there a way to use behaviours as a type in typespecs?** Can my function spec say that args should implement my behaviour, or should I just use `module()/atom()`?

Comment: Why you would like to check that, since its developers job to implement the behaviour in specific modules, is it somehow related to user input? If its not related to user input I think you should not check that.

Comment: Mostly to make the error more of a "this should implement this behavior" instead of "this function is undefined" and to check it before doing anything else, but I'm leaning towards just making the assumption that everything is good to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.

> Are behaviours more about "I want to make sure I implement everything needed" than "I want everyone else to know I implement everything needed"?

My understanding is that a behavior is a contract between a module author and the user of that module to say: "I expect you to provide me with a module that can do all of these things". So it is the responsibility of the module user to do that.

The fact that the keyword for a behaviour function is `@callback` seems to me to say that usually the module that defines the behaviour is also that module that will be consuming that behaviour (in other words, calling the callback). It seems to be the responsibility of the behaviour implementor to make sure it correctly implements the behaviour, with a compile-time check to help them out, but there is no run-time help for the user of a module that requires the behaviour to make sure they actually provided a valid implementation.

Your solution to provide a run-time warning looks good to me - however it's possible to implement a behaviour without providing the `@behaviour` attribute, so it will not work well in that case.

There is a slightly more helpful error message if the behaviour implementor declared `@behaviour` in their code but ignored the compiler warning:

> warning: function foo/0 required by behaviour ExpectBehaviour is not implemented (in module ClaimsItImplementsButDoesNot)

```elixir
iex> ExpectBehaviour.use_behaviour(ClaimsItImplementsButDoesNot)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ClaimsItImplementsButDoesNot.foo/0 is undefined or private,
   but the behaviour ExpectBehaviour expects it to be present
```

However this is not the case if you simply pass an unrelated module that doesn't implement the behaviour:

```elixir
iex> ExpectBehaviour.use_behaviour(DoesNotImplementOrClaimTo)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function DoesNotImplementOrClaimTo.foo/0 is undefined or private
```

> Is there a way to use behaviours as a type in typespecs?

A behaviour is not a type, it's a specification of a set of functions, and a module can implement multiple behaviours, so I don't think this makes sense. As mentioned above, it seems sensible to keep the use of a behaviour's callbacks constrained to the module where it's defined.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I think I was thinking of behaviours too much like interfaces in other, more statically-typed languages.

Comment: Necro-comment: a `String.t()` isn't really a distinct type either, it's a limitation of the more general `binary` type. Decorating a module with the behavior(s) it implements makes a lot of sense when I think about it this way. Especially since an important use is dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce it during compile time you can also do:

```
defmodule Lib.EnforcedBehaviour do

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote location: :keep do
      @aftercompile Lib.EnforcedBehaviour
      @behaviour Lib.EnforcedBehaviour
    end
  end

  @callback enforced_function() :: atom

  def __after_compile__(%{module: module} = _env) do
    if !Kernel.function_exported?(module, :enforced_function, 0) do
      raise "expected implementation of 'enforced_function/0' in #{inspect module}."
    end  
  end

end
```

This is quite ugly, but works.

You can now do:

```
# Will fail during compilation
defmodule Lib.EnforcingBehaviour do
  use Lib.EnforcedBehaviour
end

# Will not fail during compilation
defmodule Lib.EnforcingBehaviour do
  use Lib.EnforcedBehaviour

  def enforced_function() do
  end

end
```

**BUT**: Please don't do this :smile: